# create feature in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

im trying to biuld a aurelia plugin beside of no complete doc and i read too many doc and plugin im build a simple plugin that contain a simple date picker:

first of all i create below filesystem :

```
 ./Aurelia
   -JbPlugin
        -JbDirectives
           +index.js
           +jb-calendar.js
```

and in main.js file i add it with feature like below:

```js
aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .feature('jb-directive');
```

after that in index.js file of plugin i have:

```js
import {ViewLocator , inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {JbCalendar} from './jb-calendar';

export function configure(config) {
    config.globalResources([
          './jb-calendar']
      );
}

export {
    JbCalendar,
};
```

in jb-calendar.js:

```js
import {inject, bindable, bindingMode, BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class JbCalendar {
}
```

in my config.js file:

```js
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system",
      "es7.decorators",
      "es7.classProperties"
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "jb-plugin:*":"Aurelia/JbPlugin/*"
  },
  stage: 0,

  map: {
    "jb-directive": "jb-plugin:jb-directive",
    "aurelia-animator-css": "npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.1",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@2.0.1",
    "aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@1.1.0",
    "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.8",
    "aurelia-http-client": "npm:aurelia-http-client@1.0.4",
    "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.1.0",
    "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.1.1",
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.38",
    "babel-polyfill": "npm:babel-polyfill@6.23.0",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.7",
    "jquery": "npm:jquery@3.1.1",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
      "assert": "npm:assert@1.4.1"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0": {
      "buffer": "npm:buffer@3.6.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0": {
      "path-browserify": "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.11.9"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0": {
      "vm-browserify": "npm:vm-browserify@0.0.4"
    },
    "npm:assert@1.4.1": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.1": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-binding@1.1.1": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.1.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@2.0.1": {
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.1",
      "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.8",
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.1.0",
      "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.0": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.1": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.8": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.1.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0": {
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-http-client@1.0.4": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0": {
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.1.0": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.1.1": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.1.0": {
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-router@1.1.1": {
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.1",
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-route-recognizer": "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.1.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.1.0": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.1.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.1": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating@1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.0",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.1.0"
    },
    "npm:babel-polyfill@6.23.0": {
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@6.23.0",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@2.4.1",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "regenerator-runtime": "npm:regenerator-runtime@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:babel-runtime@6.23.0": {
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@2.4.1",
      "regenerator-runtime": "npm:regenerator-runtime@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm:buffer@3.6.0": {
      "base64-js": "npm:base64-js@0.0.8",
      "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "ieee754": "npm:ieee754@1.1.8",
      "isarray": "npm:isarray@1.0.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:core-js@1.2.7": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:core-js@2.4.1": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:inherits@2.0.1": {
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:process@0.11.9": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "vm": "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:regenerator-runtime@0.10.3": {
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:util@0.10.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:vm-browserify@0.0.4": {
      "indexof": "npm:indexof@0.0.1"
    }
  }
});
```

in package.json file i have:

```js
{
  "jspm": {
    "main": "index",
    "format": "amd",
    "dependencies": {
      "aurelia-animator-css": "npm:aurelia-animator-css@^1.0.1",
      "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@^2.0.1",
      "aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@^1.1.0",
      "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@^1.0.8",
      "aurelia-http-client": "npm:aurelia-http-client@^1.0.4",
      "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@^1.1.0",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@^1.1.1",
      "babel-polyfill": "npm:babel-polyfill@^6.23.0",
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@^3.1.1",
      "jb-directive": "jb-plugin:jb-directive"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
    }
  }
}
```

so it work well without any error and load all js but when i want to use the plugin in real class like dashboard js as below:

```
import {JbCalendar} from 'jb-directive';
```

it throw an error to me :

```
 GET http://localhost:9001/Aurelia/JbPlugin/jb-directive.js 404 (Not Found)
```

why aurelia route plugin like top ?doesnt it soppose to load index.js file?

Edited:
       i findout my plugin is work fine what i need is just to use directive without any "import" in class becuase i add my directive in global resources it can be used anyway in app without import

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .developmentLogging()
  .plugin('JbPlguins/JbDirectives');
```

Comment: no problem is remain and it look for jb-directive.js or jbDirective.js

Comment: GET http://localhost:9001/Aurelia/JbPlugin/jbDirective.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: He's creating a plugin, not a feature, so he'd need to use the `plugin` function.

Comment: WOW! You're right @AshleyGrant. The question title says 'feature' and I  didn't pay enough attention to the code. He's actually creating a plugin :) . My bad :(

Comment: @javadbat try using `plugin` instead of `feature`

Comment: @FabioLuz I mean.. I'm not right often, but when I'm right, I'm right. :-P